# Log4j2 - xml to properties configuration with multiple loggers

Tags: java, log4j2

```
<Loggers>
    <!-- Apache Struts2 logger -->
    <Logger name="org.apache.struts2" level="warn" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Logger>
    <!-- Spring logger -->
    <Logger name="org.springframework" level="warn" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Logger>
    <!-- Root logger -->
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Above is a snippet of the log4j2.xml configuration file and I would like to convert it into the properties.

The problem is when I define multiple loggers in the same file (properties), only the root logger works meaning changing the level on other loggers does not do a thing.

What is the correct way of defining multiple loggers in the same properties config file?

Edit:

```
logger.rolling.name = org.apache.struts2
logger.rolling.level = warn

logger.rolling.name = org.springframework
logger.rolling.level = warn

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
```

This is the properties config I have tried but it didn't work.

Comment: can you post your properties file too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below configuration -

```
logger.rolling1.name = org.apache.struts2
logger.rolling1.level = warn
logger.rolling1.additivity = false
logger.rolling1.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
logger.rolling1.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile

logger.rolling2.name = org.springframework
logger.rolling2.level = warn
logger.rolling2.additivity = false
logger.rolling2.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
logger.rolling2.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

Answer (score -1):

Will - you need to add categories like this..

### log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - <%m>%n

log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.DB.URL=.....
log4j.appender.DB.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
log4j.appender.DB.user=...
log4j.appender.DB.password=...
log4j.appender.DB.sql=INSERT INTO BATCH_LOG VALUES("%x","%d","%C","%p","%m")
log4j.appender.DB.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.category.org.apache.activemq=INFO
log4j.category.org.springframework.batch=INFO
log4j.category.org.springframework.transaction=INFO
```

Comment: This seems like a config for log4j not log4j2. I doubt this one would even work with log4j2.